# After running permission commands AWS giving 503 error

Tags: amazon-web-services, server

In AWS EC2 instance 2 applications are running 1 is Django app and other react app. I run these two commands to give read/write permissions on Filezilla.

```
sudo chown -R ubuntu:ubuntu /var/www/html

sudo chmod -R 755 /var/www/html
```

I run them successfully and also change files for the react app through Filezilla. but the Django app gets effected after running these 2 commands throwing 503 error.

[what I'm getting on opening url](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VFKGj.png)

How can I troubleshoot AWS for this error?

Comment: is `ubuntu` the right user to own `/var/www/html`? What process is actually reading that?

Comment: Login to the instance and check some logs.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with:

```
sudo chown -R ubuntu:www-data .
```

When you're inside html folder?

That worked for me. (Made a clean install of Apache2 and PHP and got 503 error everytime until this).